# Javascript : Unable to scroll smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Sorry but It is fixed, soon I will delete this question :)**

I am trying to create a scroll effect in which different `<Section>` stacks over each other as you scroll down, but There is a weird sudden snap when we reach at the top where a section need to be `position:fixed` and the element below it need to scroll

Please see the codepen example and scroll slowly 
[codepen code](http://codepen.io/alexakasanjeev/pen/xgXEvE?editors=0110)

Comment: Is it browser-specific ? I don't see any snapping in your example neither in Chrome nor Firefox.

Comment: Same here. Seems to be no issue.

Comment: Sorry the code was broken I just fixed it please give a look one more time :)

Comment: I see a snap when the nav bar get hidden and the "Message from head" snaps to the top

Comment: @gotomanners yes but the problem is it happen very fast due lack of correct calculation of heights and margin-top property, if you will scroll very slowly you can see the weird snap

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi  the code was broken earlier please give a look

Comment: if I understood you good, it is just some math problems on your JS

Comment: @Drix yes but i can't figure it out,ban you help me

Comment: Your CSS moving things proportionally and your JS doesn't count for it, I did fix the first one, the second need to find the CSS affecting it and change the JS accordingly

Comment: @Drix thank you I figured it out :) it was just simple math problem